# Woocommerce: How to show product page on top of checkout?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to show product page on top of checkout page.
I think I need a php code to put on top of form-checkout.php. I am using a parallax theme.
please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you can put on top of the form-checkout.php:

```
<?php
$args = array( 
'post_type' => 'product', 
'orderby'=> 'date',
'posts_per_page'=> 6
 ); 
 $myquery = new WP_Query($args);
 if ( $myquery->have_posts() ) : ?>
 <?php while ( $myquery->have_posts() ) : $myquery->the_post(); 
 //example, display a list of title 
 ?>
  <?php 
    //display product thumbnail

    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) { 

    }
    else {
      echo '';
    }
   echo ''; 
   endwhile; ?>

   <?php else : ?>
   <p>Not Found</p>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Which product page do you want to show?

You can modify your form-checkout.php file, but if you update the WooCommerce plugin the changes will be lost.

Create a child theme for this file in your themes folder.

Also I will rather use action filters to hook in to the right directions. You need to insert your code in your functions.php file.

See [Hooks: Action and Filter reference](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply beamkiller. The way i made the product page has navigation's so that you can navigate all the products on one page. now the thing is i have to show that page on top of checkout options. the_permalink () is not working.

Comment: You can use something like this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/showing-one-pages-content-on-another-page
Then in functions.php also add the filter for checkout.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form' , 'custom_override_checkout' );

You need to create the custom_override_checkout function with the page call, which is explained on the page what I have inserted :).

Comment: Thank again beamkiller. I managed to get page title, description, product image. but the problem is the products have variables like color and size. I dont see any filter for variables and add to cart button.

Comment: If you want display products the easiest way is to use WooCommerce shortcodes :). See this: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/  You can choose which product do you wanna show, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to put checkout page on the product page. Code below will add checkout below each product in the shop.

```
function add_checkout_to_product_page() {
  echo do_shortcode ('[woocommerce_checkout]');
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'add_checkout_to_product_page', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: you have an extra " ?>" in there